# Count the rows of a table, while checking if the value is NULL or not and grouping the results by the values of another column

Tags: mysql, count, conditional-statements

I am stuck trying to find a solution to my silly little problem.

The MySQL table looks as follows:

```
-- Create a table that will record all AdCamp hits
CREATE TABLE `advertising_campaign_hits` (
`adcamp_hit_id` INT     NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`adcamp_id` INT,
`customer_id` INT,
`recorded_at` DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (`adcamp_hit_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Example values would look like this:

```
a_h_id | a_id | c_id | ... 
   1   |   1  |   1  | ... 
   2   |   1  |   2  | ...
   3   |   1  |   3  | ...
   4   |   1  |   0  | ...
   5   |   1  |   0  | ...
   6   |   2  |   1  | ...
   7   |   2  |   0  | ...
```

The goal here is to count the number of hits for each of the advertising campaigns, but divide them into two groups of KnownCustomers and UnknownCustomers and then further divide them each by adcamp_id.

So the results I would expect to get are:

```
adcamp_id | HitsByKnown |  HitsByUnknown
    1     |     3       |       2
    2     |     1       |       1
```

I am currently stuck in where I can get SQL to give me two separate rows for each of the adcamps, but the results of COUNT(*) list all of my entries.

So what I get is:

```
adcamp_id | HitsByKnown |  HitsByUnknown
    1     |     4       |       3
    2     |     4       |       3
```

I can't figure out how to split it all up.

Answer (score 0):

select adcamp_id,sum(if(customer_id>0,1,0)) as HitsByKnown,sum(if(customer_id=0,1,0)) as HitsByUnknown from advertising_campaign_hits group by adcamp_id

or even easier:

select adcamp_id,sum(customer_id!=0) as HitsByKnown,sum(customer_id=0) as HitsByUnknown from advertising_campaign_hits group by adcamp_id

Comment: So simple...Thank you kindly for the help. That did it.